# could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, playframework

We've a web application build in play framework which uses Postgres 9.6. It works fine. However, we're trying to install Postgres 13, so our application use Postgres 13, instead of Postgres 9.6. This is Amazon Linux 2 (EC2) machine running Linux.

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.14.252-195.483.amzn2.x86_64 (mockbuild@ip-1-0-1-1) (gcc version 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-13) (GCC))
```

I've installed Postgres 13 via amazon-linux-extras:

```
postgresql.x86_64                  13.3-2.amzn2.0.1                  @amzn2extra-postgresql13
```

*This machine already have Postgres 9.6.*

Some other packages installed on the machine are:

```
# yum list installed | grep -i postgre
libpq.x86_64                       13.3-1.amzn2                      @amzn2extra-postgresql13
libpq-devel.x86_64                 13.3-1.amzn2                      @amzn2extra-postgresql13
postgresql.x86_64                  13.3-2.amzn2.0.1                  @amzn2extra-postgresql13
postgresql-contrib.x86_64          13.3-2.amzn2.0.1                  @amzn2extra-postgresql13
postgresql-server.x86_64           13.3-2.amzn2.0.1                  @amzn2extra-postgresql13
postgresql-server-devel.x86_64     13.3-2.amzn2.0.1                  @amzn2extra-postgresql13
postgresql96.x86_64                9.6.24-1PGDG.rhel6                @pgdg96
postgresql96-devel.x86_64          9.6.24-1PGDG.rhel6                @pgdg96
postgresql96-libs.x86_64           9.6.24-1PGDG.rhel6                @pgdg96
postgresql96-server.x86_64         9.6.24-1PGDG.rhel6                @pgdg96
```

Note: I removed `postgresql96-contrib.x86_64` to fix the error but that dosen't help!

While launching web applictaion, below error is coming:

```
[ERROR] - from play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi in main - ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:58P01]
```

The file does exist:

```
# ll /usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 178 Jun 21  2021 /usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control
```

```
# ll /usr/lib64/pgsql/uuid-ossp.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11272 Jun 21  2021 /usr/lib64/pgsql/uuid-ossp.so
```

```
bash-4.2$ psql
psql (13.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
CREATE EXTENSION

postgres=# select uuid_generate_v1();
           uuid_generate_v1
--------------------------------------
 49634f70-6329-11ec-87cf-020c60b9374c
(1 row)
```

```
# pg_config
BINDIR = /usr/bin
DOCDIR = /usr/share/doc/pgsql
HTMLDIR = /usr/share/doc/pgsql
INCLUDEDIR = /usr/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /usr/include/pgsql
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /usr/include/pgsql/server
LIBDIR = /usr/lib64
PKGLIBDIR = /usr/lib64/pgsql
LOCALEDIR = /usr/share/locale
MANDIR = /usr/share/man
SHAREDIR = /usr/share/pgsql
SYSCONFDIR = /etc
PGXS = /usr/lib64/pgsql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE =  '--build=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--disable-rpath' '--with-ldap' '--with-openssl' '--with-gssapi' '--enable-nls' '--without-readline' '--datadir=/usr/share/pgsql' 'build_alias=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-koji-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches    -m64 -mtune=generic' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro ' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches    -m64-mtune=generic' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig'
CC = gcc
CPPFLAGS = -D_GNU_SOURCE
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3-Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches    -m64 -mtune=generic
CFLAGS_SL = -fPIC
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed
LDFLAGS_EX =
LDFLAGS_SL =
LIBS = -lpgcommon -lpgport -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm
VERSION = PostgreSQL 13.3
```

I've tried adding `/usr/lib64/pgsql`  in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` and running `ldconfig` but that dosen't help. I tried after restarting Postgres 13.

I’m all out of ideas. What am I missing?

Comment: what method are you using to upgrade?

Comment: My bad! I should remove the word "upgrade". As my approach is not to upgrade. Rather, install Postgres 13 and start on port 5432. Our application uses 5432 to connect and creates all the required tables on startup. Postgres 9.6 is shutdown on this machine.

Comment: perhaps a permissions error on the file/directory in question?

Comment: This `Jun 21  2021 /usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control` is suspicious? If you just installed Postgres 13.3(FYI, 13.5 is latest minor release) I would expect a later file date. So either you are looking in wrong place or the `postgresql-contrib.x86_64` did not actually get installed.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I don't think `Jun 21` is an installation date. Because, to verify this I removed `postgresql-contrib.x86_64` and there were no `/usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control`. I then reinstalled `postgresql-contrib.x86_64` and date is again `Jun 21` and file is present as well.

Comment: @VynlJunkie I'm also having a doubt regarding permission issue. But I've another EC2 machine where postgres 9.6 is installed and permission of `uuid-ossp.control` looks same what I've on this machine (the one I'm getting error on). For reference I'm listing both here:

9.6 machine: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 163 Nov 12  2019 /usr/pgsql-9.6/share/extension/uuid-ossp.control`

13 machine (having error): `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 178 Jun 21  2021 /usr/share/pgsql/extension/uuid-ossp.control`

What does `163` and `178` represents above? Are there any system logs where perm issues are registered?

Comment: So far I'm not able to fix this issue. I think it has something to do with some library path / or some dynamic linking path, if there is one. Because, the file is present and app is not able to find it. Looks like a path issue or maybe missing symlink.

Comment: I'm betting it has to do with the 9.6 and 13 instances being installed from different sources. Why not install 13 from the PGDG repos like the 9.6 instance?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm trying to follow your advise i.e installing PG 13 via PGDG repo, but now am facing a different issue of installing "postgresql13-devel.x86_64" which is required for plv8 build and is not available via PGDG repo.

Comment: I tried installing via PGDG repo, but got the same error. However, dropping `play_evolutions` table has resolved this error finally.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing via PGDG repo, but got the same error. However, dropping `play_evolutions` table has resolved this error finally. I see this table was having the error and the corresponding plv8 creation query. I'm not 100% sure why dropping this table has resolved the error. But I think play framework was picking something from cache using this table due to which the error was repeating. I also think this error was more related to play framework than Postgres.